# How to Integrate multiple unit test reports with SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, cobertura, sonarqube-scan, maven-cobertura-plugin

I have couple of Maven projects in my build. Each project has its unit test cases. I would like to execute those test cases & report the consolidated results on SonarQube Server. I am on SonarQube 5.6.

As there are multiple Cobertura reports to combine, I could not find a better way other than go with https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Generic+Test+Coverage

I used https://github.com/QualInsight/qualinsight-mojo-cobertura to generate report in generic format.

At sonar level, I do not have multiple modules defined.

**Questions**

1. In my build there are couple of other projects developed using C#, JS/html. I want to see the consolidated report from all the projects (irrespective of language) integrated on SonarServer. Is using Generic Test Coverage the right  approach?
2. When I run the build then I can see the coverage.xml & converted-coverage.xml files generated. I set the path sonar.genericcoverage.reportPaths & sonar.genericcoverage.unitTestReportPaths as well. but nothing is coming up for unit testing on Sonar portal. I checked the logs & get following

> INFO: Sensor GenericCoverageSensor
>       INFO: Parsing Mycode\target\cobertura\ut\converted-coverage.xml
>       INFO: Imported coverage data for 0 files
>       INFO: coverage data ignored for 33 unknown files, including:
>       src/main/java/com/app/AppInfoService.java
>       src/main/java/com/app/Service.java
>       src/main/java/com/app/F1Service.java
>       src/main/java/com/app/JobService.java
>       src/main/java/com/app/L1.java
>       INFO: Imported IT coverage data for 0 files
>       INFO: Imported Overall coverage data for 0 files
>       INFO: Imported unit test data for 0 files
>   What is missing here, Why sonar not able to parse the generic code coverage report.

Any help is much appreciated.

Atul